# What is the point of having KNOX?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-4, samsung-knox

I'm about to use Odin to root my S4 running 5.0.1, but I'd just like to know, what is the point of KNOX and is it really important? I know it's not just the software I'm not authorized to use, and it'll set my KNOX warranty flag to 0x1 and burn the e-fuse, but I'd just like to reassure myself that I'm not missing out on something here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Samsung knox is, beside some device hardening, a container or dual persona solution for Android. Think of the knox container as a second completely independent instance of Android running on your phone with own apps, data and settings. It is mostly used by companies to implement bring-your-own-device solutions. However, you can also use it as a private user, but I am not really aware of any great use case for this... so you need to decide whether you want to use the container. I guess the most users can safely ignore it.